# Get the name of column header and export to different excel worksheet

Tags: excel, pull-request, summarize

I have to work with different checklists in different Excel workbooks in order to organize the progress.

I made a summary where I set a counter in the number of items that I am missing for different workbooks using the formula shown here:

```
=SUM(LEN(XXX)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(XXX,"pending","")))/LEN("pending")
```

However, in order to not have to consult to each of the workbooks to find out which items are pending to complete, I am requesting some guidance to understand if it's possible to say that:

If item in cell is pending, extract the name to a different cell in my summary.

Here's an example workbook:

[image: workbook example]

Summary example

[image: summary example]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Comment and a partial solution.
I am ignoring the the cross workbook issues for simplicity.
Get the basics working and deal with that later.

In the formula

```
=SUM(LEN(XXX)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(XXX,"pending","")))/LEN("pending")
```

the sum function is not used correctly.  Sum add up all the numbers in
a list and/or range of cells.  You have a expression. It will work but is not needed.

`=(LEN(XXX)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(XXX,"pending","")))/LEN("pending")`
should work.

As for the sum of the item tagged with "pending" that can be done with a couple of extra rows that would be hidden in your final sheet.

[image: sample]

In the sample sheet. Rows 4 and 5 are intermidate calculation rows that will be hidden for final display.
Row 4 has the same relative formula :
=if(B3="pending",B2,"")
for all cells. It copies the data in row 2 only if row 3 has the word "pending".

The objective is to concatenate all of the non blank details
into one cell.  I chose a solution that would with Excel 2003+. (2019 could use TextJoin() as an alternative solution)

in row 5 Cell b5 has

```
=if(len(B4)>0,B4,"")
```

Starting with C5 the rest have the relative formula

```
=if(len(B5)>0,if(len(C4)>0,B5&"+"&C4,B5),C4)
```

This progressively concatenates the cells together ignoring blank cells.
F5 has the answer needed

C8 has the

```
=COUNTif(B3:F3,"pending")
```

To count the number missing

and D8  just points as F5 to pick up the results.

For presentation purposes hide  rows 4 and 5.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly and i'm actually looking in closer detail to the CONCATENATE because i think it will help me further to match between different workbooks. thank you